# $C_0$ semigroups on parameterized Banach spaces or moving domains

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, semigroups-of-operators

Is there any literature corresponding to one or two-parameter semigroups such that e.g. $T(t) \in \mathcal{L}(X(t))$ or $T(s,t) \in \mathcal{L}(X(t),X(s))$ for parameterized Banach spaces $X(t)$?

I have only seen the case where $X(t) \equiv X$ (i.e. there is only one Banach space).

This may be useful for PDE problems where there are moving domains.

Comment: I don't see how one-parameter semigroups would fit. The semigroup law $T(t)T(s)=T(t+s)$ only makes sense if $T(t)$ and $T(s)$ act on the same Banach space?

Comment: @gsa: This can be remedied if one requires $T(t)\in \bigcap_{a} Hom(X(a),X(a+t))$ or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find many things about such operator families in the literature, but what there is is for the non-autonomous case. See for example

- M. Geissert & A. Lunardi [Invariant Measures and Maximal L2
  Regularity for Nonautonomous Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Equations.](http://www.math.unipr.it/~lunardi/Files/glOUrevised.pdf) J.
  Lond. Math. Soc. (2) 77 (2008), no. 3, 719-740.

where the evolution family $P_{s,t}$ acts between spaces $L^p(\nu_t)$ and $L^p(\nu_s)$ with a suitable family of measures $\nu_t$.